# How can I createprocess in windows and not wait for it to complete?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a little windows c++ program that just fires off other programs, but I find when I kill my parent program, all the children die. I want to spawn them off with no relation to the parent anymore. I don't want to wait for output, I don't even care too much if it worked or not. But it is important that it not be tied to the parent process, because it can go away at random.
The docs aren't terribly forthcoming on this subject.

This is what I've got.

```
if (CreateProcess(NULL, s, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
  {
    // don't wait for it to finish.
    //::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    // free up resources...
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
  }
else
  log error...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to pass [`CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx#CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP) in the `dwCreationFlags` parameter.

Comment: So, does this mean that even if I CloseHandle for hProcess and hThread, it would not affect the New Process created?

Comment: @Abhinet Closing a handle to a process or thread does not terminate either of them. It just means that you no longer have handles to those objects.

Comment: Oh Yeah...I think I need some sleep :-) Thanks anyways!